# Inequality $(a^b+b^a)(a^{b+1}+b^{a+1})\geq 1$

Tags: inequality, exponentiation

It's a following
 problem:

> Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ then we have :
>   $$(a^b+b^a)(a^{b+1}+b^{a+1})\geq 1$$

I try to use Tchebytchev inequality to get a sum but it's too weak as approximation .

I try otherwise something like :
$$(a^b+b^a)\geq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$$

But it doesn't work.

I don't know if it's relevant but the function :

$$f(x)=(x^{(1-x)+1}+(1-x)^{x+1})$$ is convex on $[0,1]$

Maybe we need a really new approach to solve it .

Thanks a lot for your time and patience .

Comment: If you know the concavity, might try Jensen's inequality. Might work

Comment: Wolfy agrees with mins of 1 at 0, .5, 1 and maxs of about 1.011 at about .2 and .8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Probably not finished.*

Because of the symmetry, we only need to focus on the range $0\leq a \leq \frac 12$ after having replaced $b$ by $(1-a)$.

Now, consider the function
$$f(a)=(a^b+b^a)(a^{b+1}+b^{a+1})\qquad \text{where} \qquad b=1-a$$ The function value is $1$ for $a=0$ and $a=\frac 12$.

Expansions at both ends of the interval are
$$f(a)=1-(\log (a)+2)a^2 +\left(\frac{\log ^2(a)}{2}+1\right)a^3 +O\left(a^4\right)$$
$$f(a)=1+ \left(\log ^2(2)+4\log
   (2)-3\right)\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+O\left(\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)^4\right)$$ At least we know that the function starts and ends with valuee equal to $1$.

Performing a similar expansion around $a=\frac{1}{4}$ up to $O\left(\left(a-\frac{1}{4}\right)^4\right)$ (too messy formula to be reported here shows that the function is maximum at $a=0.194853$ (the exact solution being $a=0.193776$). For this approximate value of $a$, the maximum value is predicted to be $1.01083$ which is exactly the value at the exact maximum.

Comment: What's missing in your proof ?

Comment: @The.old.boy. I think that it is OK but I am still looking for (I hope !) something better.